# How to use nusoap to consume an online webservice?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

Recently, I've been trying to use nusoap in order to consume an online webservice. I have already successfully used nusoap to create a web server and a web client locally. I have been able to use my client to call a soap request on the server I created in localhost.
Now, I am trying to use a nusoap client in order to send a soap request to an online server. In particular, I have been trying to send a soap request to " http://www.herongyang.com/Service/Hello_WSDL_11_SOAP.wsdl "  which is an active wsdl file.

```
$client=new nusoap_client("http://www.herongyang.com/Service/Hello_WSDL_11_SOAP.wsdl");
  echo $response = $client->call('Hello', "Hello from client.");
  echo 'do we reach here'.$response;
```

the code that is given in the tutorial is

```
   <?php 
# SOAP_Hello.php
# Copyright (c) 2009 by Dr. Herong Yang, herongyang.com
# All rights reserved
   $client = new SoapClient(
      "http://www.herongyang.com/Service/Hello_WSDL_11_SOAP.wsdl");
   echo $client->Hello("Hello from client.");
?>
```

This doesn't use nusoap - but hopefully is helpful to someone looking at this question. The link to the tutorial is http://www.herongyang.com/WSDL/PHP-SOAP-Configure-and-Test-SOAP-Extension.html . I'm wondering if I am somehow misusing the syntax of nusoap, or if my localhost client can't send requests through the internet. I've checked online at a generic soap client generator and the site is active AND the parameter requested is "Hello".

Comment: What are you getting in respone in your nusoap client?

Comment: I'm not getting anything. When I echo $response I receive a blank page. (i.e. I'm not printing anything)